# How to create a switch expression with UITextFields in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, switch-statement, uitextfield, swift3

I want to check my `UITextFields` for their `.text` status. Execute a function on `!= ""` and show an alert view `if == ""`. Since I have 5 different `UITextFields` I thought of a `switch` statement.

```
@IBAction func doneButton(_ sender: Any) {

    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
    let cell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! SetupCell

    var textFields: [UITextField] = []

    textFields = [cell.nameTF,
                  cell.townTF,
                  cell.birthdayTF,
                  cell.genreTF,
                  cell.deejayTF]

    for tf in textFields {

        print("called") // is printed

        if tf.text != "" {

            print("not empty") // is printed

            switch UITextField() {
            case cell.nameTF:
                saveCredential(ME, "name", cell.nameTF.text!)
            case cell.birthdayTF:
                saveCredential(ME, "birthday", cell.birthdayTF.text!)
            case cell.townTF:
                saveCredential(ME, "town", cell.townTF.text!)
            case cell.deejayTF:
                saveCredential(ME, "deejayName", cell.deejayTF.text!)
            case cell.genreTF:
                saveCredential(ME, "genre", cell.genreTF.text!)
            default:
                break
            }
        } else {

            print("is empty") // printed

            switch UITextField() {
            case cell.nameTF:
                presentAlertView(self, title: "Error", message: "Name missing")
            case cell.birthdayTF:
                presentAlertView(self, title: "Error", message: "Birthday missing")
            case cell.townTF:
                presentAlertView(self, title: "Error", message: "Town missing")
            case cell.deejayTF:
                presentAlertView(self, title: "Error", message: "Deejay name missing")
            case cell.genreTF:
                presentAlertView(self, title: "Error", message: "Genre missing")
            default:
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But the code within the `switch` statement is not executed. Neither the case if empty, nor if not. I believe the problem may be in `switch UITextField()`, but I can't figure out a solution. What am I missing? Help is very appreciated.

PS. The `saveCredential` as well as the `presentAlertView` are perfectly working on other parts of the App, so that might not be the issue. But to be sure:

```
func presentAlertView(_ vc: UIViewController, title: String, message: String?) {
    var alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: nil, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
    if message != nil {
        alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
    }
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
    vc.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are passing the new instance of `UITextFiled` with `switch` statements instead of passing object from `Array`.

```
switch tf {
```

Instead of

```
switch UITextField() {
```

Comment: thank you, that did it. will accept as soon as possible

Comment: @DavidSeek Welcome mate :)